# Can I Handle These Requirements?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, cpu, intel-graphics

A game I want to run has these requirements:

```
Operating System: Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7
Processor: Dual Core 2.0 GHz or equivalent
RAM: 2GB
Required Hard Disk Space: 15GB
Graphics Card: 256MB ATIx800 or NVIDA 6800 card (or better)
```

Can my PC:

```
Operating System: Windows 7 (64 bit)
Processor: Intel Celeron 900 processor 2.2GHz, 800MHz Front Side Bus, 1MB Cache
RAM: 2GB
Hard Disk Space: 152GB
Graphics Card: Intel GMA 4500M Dynamic Video Memory Technology 5.0
```

handle it? Will it run slowly or will it be just fine? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are those the minimum or recommended requirements?

Comment: @johnh : recommended. But I wanted to get best quality.

Comment: I'm not going to answer properly because I'm unfamiliar with the graphics card side, but my feeling is that the Celeron will be unplayably slow for you. That said, however, the on-board cache for the CPU makes all the difference, and 1MB *may* be enough.

Comment: @RandolphWest : So the Celeron is holding me back?

Comment: Yes, but see my comments on @music2myear's answer. I think you need a stronger CPU.

Comment: The architecture of the system is holding you back. You could get a better CPU and it may make a small difference. But your integrated GPU isn't that great either. This system simply isn't designed for gaming at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, your system does not meet the minimum requirements.

You can see this yourself by googling your processor, which will bring up the first result of the Intel page describing it: http://ark.intel.com/products/41498/Intel-Celeron-Processor-900-(1M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)

The number of cores is only 1 and the number of threads is only 1. So your computer does not meet the CPU requirement.

Your graphics chipset is optimized for video, not gaming. It may work, but not very well, and really only if you have  better CPU: http://www.intel.com/products/notebook/chipsets/gm45/gm45-overview.htm

Your system was designed for business users, not gaming. It's a laptop, right?

Comment: Yes it's a laptop. But these are the recommended requirements. Minimum for the processor is `Intel Pentium 4 2.0 GHz or equivalent`. Is that good enough?

Comment: actually, go to this site to see the requirements: http://us.runesofmagic.com/us/downloads,id4,runes_magic_client.html

Comment: You said the minimum was Dual Core, not Pentium 4. So which is it?

Comment: According to my interpretation of the URL provided, your Celeron may be sufficient, but I still think it will hold you back.

Comment: Yes barely. The Celeron CPU is a very, very weak CPU that has only one strength: not much. ;) Well, it's OK with office apps and such. Any time you try running a multimedia app, your Celeron will choke. That's just how it works. It's not made for it. Yes, it'll be faster than a P4 in clock speed, but that doesn't mean much considering all the other aspects of a CPU that factor into what you and I truly perceive as "speed".

Comment: @music2myear The Celeron 900 smokes every Pentium 4 ever made at just about every possible application. I think you're either forgetting how old the Pentium 4s are or you're confusing the Celeron 900 (circa 2009) with the much older NetBurst-based Celerons (circa 2002-4).